# login issue with aws command line interface with MFA code/token

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

With amazon aws command line interface, I can't successfully login with MFA token

**I can login via web interface, MFA has been enable**. If I login via web interface, I need provide: `Account`, `User Name`, `Password`, enable MFA token, `MFA code`

**Now I need do it from command line interface**, installed awscli tool, following amazon document http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE      # I think this is Username
aws_secret_access_key=wJalrXUtnFEM          # I think this is Password
aws_session_token=example123324             # I think this is MFA code
```

Not sure how to set AWS `Account (or called alias)` and enable MFA token option.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the wrong credentials for logging into the AWS web console.

What you are showing is the **Access Key** (they always start with *AKI*) of the **Access Credentials** (you could also use a *Signing Certificate*).

To log into the web console you need **Sign-In Credentials**, which consist of a username (email) and a password. Optionally, you can (and should) also enable Multi-Factor Authentication.

You have selected the Account Alias when you signed up for AWS. If you have forgotten it, but still have a working Access Key, see the documentation on how to retrieve the alias: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-account-aliases.html

Comment: I can login from web interface with MFA token, my request here is to login by command line for further automatic scripting

Comment: I just realised the right way to login via command line when have MFA enable is separate access key. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/get-aws-keys.html . `Getting Your AWS Access Keys

After you've signed up for Amazon SES, you'll need to obtain your AWS access keys if you want to access Amazon SES through the Amazon SES API, whether by the Query (HTTPS) interface directly or indirectly through an AWS SDK, the AWS Command Line Interface or the AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell. AWS access keys consist of an access key ID and a secret access key.`

Answer (score 5):

From mid-October, there is an actual solution to this problem: the [aws-cli](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html) now supports assuming a role and use a MFA-based getting the role.

The way to use it is explained in [this article](https://cloudonaut.io/improve-aws-security-protect-your-keys-with-ease/). It works great.

BTW, some AWS-independent devs have implemented another way to use MFA with the CLI: https://github.com/lonelyplanet/aws-mfa

Comment: That's the function I am looking for currently, but not related my question I asked one year before.

Answer (score 0):

To login using mfa token you first need to integrate your mfa device (be it virtual or physical). To enable mfa token option you need to first login to web interface then go to iam then users. Now search for your user id and select it. Under security credentials tab you will get  enable mfa device option. Click on it and you will get a wizard for mfa integrations. For detailed steps follow the link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/govcloud-us/latest/UserGuide/virtual-mfa.html

Thanks

Rajarshi Haldar

Comment: I can login from web interface with MFA token, my request here is to login by command line for further automatic scripting.

Comment: Install the CLI tool and add the environment variables ``AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKI...`` plus ``AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=...`` (probably add them to your profile, bashrc, whatever) and you are good to go. There's no MFA for API keys

Comment: If I don't provide MFA keys, always get `login failed` via cli tool

Answer (score 0):

I have released very easy-to-use scripts that make it easy to enable or disable a virtual MFA device, and to start MFA and role sessions from the command line. They can be found in GitHub at https://github.com/vwal/awscli-mfa